# NSOperation with sendAsynchronousRequest completionBlock

Tags: ios, swift, nsoperation

I have a `NSOperation` subclass with the following `main` function:

```
override func main() {
    if self.cancelled {
        return
    }

    var stringResponse: String!
    var urlString: String!
    if self.arduinoConnection.arduinoHTTPPort == 80 {
        urlString = String(format: "http://%@/arduino/%@/%i/", arguments: [self.arduinoConnection.arduinoAddress, self.arduinoConnection.pinType.lowercaseString, self.arduinoConnection.arduinoPin])
    } else {
        urlString = String(format: "http://%@:%i/arduino/%@/%i/", arguments: [self.arduinoConnection.arduinoAddress, self.arduinoConnection.arduinoHTTPPort, self.arduinoConnection.pinType.lowercaseString, self.arduinoConnection.arduinoPin])
    }
    let url = NSURL(string: urlString)
    let request = NSURLRequest(URL: url!)
    NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest(request, queue: NSOperationQueue.mainQueue()) {(response, data, error) in
        println(NSString(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding))
        stringResponse = NSString(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding) as! String

        if (stringResponse == "") {
            self.arduinoConnection.state = .Failed
            self.arduinoConnection.switchState = false
            self.arduinoConnection.statusText = "Failed To Connect"
        } else {
            self.arduinoConnection.state = .Downloaded
            if (stringResponse == "0") {
                self.arduinoConnection.state = .Downloaded
                self.arduinoConnection.switchState = false
                self.arduinoConnection.statusText = "Connected"
            } else if (stringResponse == "1") {
                self.arduinoConnection.state = .Downloaded
                self.arduinoConnection.switchState = true
                self.arduinoConnection.statusText = "Connected"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My operation's state is `finished` before `NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest`'s completion handler is actually ruined. How to make `NSOperation` wait until the completion handler of `NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest` fires?

Comment: The operation is already on a background thread. So make the call synchronous not asynchronous. The reason it is getting finished is because the run loop on that thread has finished executing. You need to keep it executing on that thread. (You can mess around with stuff so that you don't need this but making it synchronous is the easiest solution).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should override `start` instead of `main`. You will have to manually fire off the notifications for `isExecuting` and `isFinished`. [Documentation here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSOperation_class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSOperation/start).

Comment: `isExecuting` and `isFinished` are read-only properties as in https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSOperation_class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSOperation/start

Comment: That's true. You can subclass `NSOperation` and make them read/write as you can see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24109701/nsoperation-property-overrides-isexecuting-isfinished