# Trying to Understand Asynchronous Operation Subclass

Tags: swift, nsoperation

I am trying to get started with using `Operation`s in a side project rather than having closure-based callbacks littered throughout my networking code to help eliminate nested calls. So I was doing some reading on the subject, and I came across [this](https://gist.github.com/calebd/93fa347397cec5f88233) implementation:

```swift
open class AsynchronousOperation: Operation {

    // MARK: - Properties

    private let stateQueue = DispatchQueue(label: "asynchronous.operation.state", attributes: .concurrent)

    private var rawState = OperationState.ready

    private dynamic var state: OperationState {
        get {
            return stateQueue.sync(execute: {
                rawState
            })
        }
        set {
            willChangeValue(forKey: "state")
            stateQueue.sync(flags: .barrier, execute: {
                rawState = newValue
            })
            didChangeValue(forKey: "state")
        }
    }

    public final override var isReady: Bool {
        return state == .ready && super.isReady
    }

    public final override var isExecuting: Bool {
        return state == .executing
    }

    public final override var isFinished: Bool {
        return state == .finished
    }

    public final override var isAsynchronous: Bool {
        return true
    }


    // MARK: - NSObject

    private dynamic class func keyPathsForValuesAffectingIsReady() -> Set<String> {
        return ["state"]
    }

    private dynamic class func keyPathsForValuesAffectingIsExecuting() -> Set<String> {
        return ["state"]
    }

    private dynamic class func keyPathsForValuesAffectingIsFinished() -> Set<String> {
        return ["state"]
    }


    // MARK: - Foundation.Operation

    public final override func start() {
        super.start()

        if isCancelled {
            finish()
            return
        }

        state = .executing
        execute()
    }


    // MARK: - Public

    /// Subclasses must implement this to perform their work and they must not call `super`. The default implementation of this function throws an exception.
    open func execute() {
        fatalError("Subclasses must implement `execute`.")
    }

    /// Call this function after any work is done or after a call to `cancel()` to move the operation into a completed state.
    public final func finish() {
        state = .finished
    }
}

@objc private enum OperationState: Int {

    case ready

    case executing

    case finished
}
```

There are some implementation details of this `Operation` subclass that I would like some help in understanding.

1. What is the purpose of the `stateQueue` property? I see it being used by `get` and `set` of the `state` computed property, but I can't find any documentation that explains the `sync:flags:execute` and `sync:execute` methods that they use.
2. What is the purpose of the three class methods in the `NSObject` section that return `["state"]`? I don't see them being used anywhere. I found, in `NSObject`, `class func keyPathsForValuesAffectingValue(forKey key: String) -> Set<String>`, but that doesn't seem to help me understand why these methods are declared.

Comment: FYI, this has a fairly serious mistake. The [`start` documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/operation/1416837-start) says (emphasis added): "If you are implementing a concurrent operation, you must override this method and use it to initiate your operation. _Your custom implementation must not call `super` at any time."_

Comment: @Rob The keyword in the quoted paragraph is "concurrent". This is relevant only for operations that _do not run in an operation queue.  See _isAsynchronous_ property and this paragraph: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/operation#1661231

Comment: @Rob None taken, but I invite you to take a closer look. I've been using operations for years. Even Apple's sample code in the famous Advanced Operations WWDC2015 talk overrides and calls super in start(). I do not say that sample code is perfect, but. I have the impression the paragraph that says you should not call super is what could be easily misunderstood.

Comment: Furthermore, what Apple calls asynchronous, is an operation that spawns a new thread from start(). This is not the same as running operations in a background queue.

Comment: Lol. I know what "asynchronous operation" means. Bottom line, the documentation couldn't be clearer about `start` implementations and they repeat the warning several times: "At no time in your `start()` method should you ever call `super`" and "Your custom implementation [of `start`] must not call `super` at any time." And I wouldn't hold out "Advanced NSOperations" as the exemplar because, as you allude, its problems are infamous and manifold. But, hey, if you want to call `super`, knock yourself out. But future readers should be forewarned, as it can cause problems if you're not careful.

Answer (score 64, accepted):

You said:

> 1. What is the purpose of the `stateQueue` property? I see it being used by get and set of the `state` computed property, but I can't find any documentation that explains the `sync:flags:execute` and `sync:execute` methods that they use.

This code "synchronizes" access to a property to make it thread safe. Regarding why you need to do that, see [the `Operation` documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/operation), which advises:

> **Multicore Considerations**
>
> ... When you subclass `NSOperation`, you must make sure that any overridden methods remain safe to call from multiple threads. If you implement custom methods in your subclass, such as custom data accessors, you must also make sure those methods are thread-safe. Thus, access to any data variables in the operation must be synchronized to prevent potential data corruption. For more information about synchronization, see [Threading Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Multithreading/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000057i).

Regarding the exact use of this concurrent queue for synchronization, this is known as the "reader-writer" pattern. This basic concept of reader-writer pattern is that reads can happen concurrent with respect to each other (hence `sync`, with no barrier), but writes must never be performed concurrently with respect to any other access of that property (hence `async` with barrier).

For example, you might implement a reader-writer for thread-safety on an array like so:

```
class ThreadSafeArray<T> {
    private var values: [T]
    private let queue = DispatchQueue(label: "...", attributes: .concurrent)
    
    init(_ values: [T]) {
        self.values = values
    }
    
    func reader<U>(block: () throws -> U) rethrows -> U {
        return try queue.sync {
            try block()
        }
    }
    
    func writer(block: @escaping (inout [T]) -> Void) {
        queue.async(flags: .barrier) {
            block(&self.values)
        }
    }
    
    // e.g. you might use `reader` and `writer` like the following:
    
    subscript(_ index: Int) -> T {
        get { reader { values[index] } }
        set { writer { $0[index] = newValue } }
    }
    
    func append(_ value: T) {
        writer { $0.append(value) }
    }
    
    func remove(at index: Int) {
        writer { $0.remove(at: index)}
    }
}
```

Obviously, the use of reader-writer in this `Operation` subclass is even simpler, but the above illustrates the pattern.

You also asked:

> 2. What is the purpose of the three class methods in the `NSObject` section that return `["state"]`? I don't see them being used anywhere. I found, in `NSObject`, `class func keyPathsForValuesAffectingValue(forKey key: String) -> Set<String>`, but that doesn't seem to help me understand why these methods are declared.

These are just methods that ensure that changes to the `state` property trigger KVO notifications for properties [`isReady`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/operation/1412992-isready), [`isExecuting`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/operation/1415621-isexecuting) and [`isFinished`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/operation/1413540-isfinished). The KVO notifications of these three keys is critical for the correct functioning of asynchronous operations. Anyway, this syntax is outlined in the [Key-Value Observing Programming Guide: Registering Dependent Keys](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueObserving/Articles/KVODependentKeys.html).

The `keyPathsForValuesAffectingValue` method you found is related. You can either register dependent keys using that method, or have the individual methods as shown in your original code snippet.

---

BTW, here is a revised version of the `AsynchronousOperation` class you provided, namely:

1. You must not call `super.start()`. As the [`start` documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/operation/1416837-start) says (emphasis added):

   > If you are implementing a concurrent operation, you must override this method and use it to initiate your operation. **Your custom implementation must not call `super` at any time.**
2. Add `@objc` required in Swift 4.
3. Renamed `execute` to use `main`, which is the convention for `Operation` subclasses.
4. It is inappropriate to declare `isReady` as a `final` property. Any subclass should have the right to further refine its `isReady` logic (though we admittedly rarely do so).
5. Use `#keyPath` to make code a little more safe/robust.
6. You don't need to do manual KVO notifications when using `dynamic` property. The manual calling of `willChangeValue` and `didChangeValue` is not needed in this example.
7. Change `finish` so that it only moves to `.finished` state if not already finished.

Thus:

```
public class AsynchronousOperation: Operation {
    
    /// State for this operation.
    
    @objc private enum OperationState: Int {
        case ready
        case executing
        case finished
    }
    
    /// Concurrent queue for synchronizing access to `state`.
    
    private let stateQueue = DispatchQueue(label: Bundle.main.bundleIdentifier! + ".rw.state", attributes: .concurrent)
    
    /// Private backing stored property for `state`.
    
    private var _state: OperationState = .ready
    
    /// The state of the operation
    
    @objc private dynamic var state: OperationState {
        get { return stateQueue.sync { _state } }
        set { stateQueue.async(flags: .barrier) { self._state = newValue } }
    }
    
    // MARK: - Various `Operation` properties
    
    open         override var isReady:        Bool { return state == .ready && super.isReady }
    public final override var isExecuting:    Bool { return state == .executing }
    public final override var isFinished:     Bool { return state == .finished }
    public final override var isAsynchronous: Bool { return true }

    // KVN for dependent properties
    
    open override class func keyPathsForValuesAffectingValue(forKey key: String) -> Set<String> {
        if ["isReady", "isFinished", "isExecuting"].contains(key) {
            return [#keyPath(state)]
        }
        
        return super.keyPathsForValuesAffectingValue(forKey: key)
    }
    
    // Start
    
    public final override func start() {
        if isCancelled {
            state = .finished
            return
        }
        
        state = .executing
        
        main()
    }
    
    /// Subclasses must implement this to perform their work and they must not call `super`. The default implementation of this function throws an exception.
    
    open override func main() {
        fatalError("Subclasses must implement `main`.")
    }
    
    /// Call this function to finish an operation that is currently executing
    
    public final func finish() {
        if !isFinished { state = .finished }
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice answer, except based on the documentation, for asynchronous operations one should override `start` instead of `main` (`main` is for synchronous operations). IMHO It would help to avoid confusion if you can remove the `main` override

Comment: I disagree. The [Concurrency Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Conceptual/ConcurrencyProgrammingGuide/OperationObjects/OperationObjects.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008091-CH101-SW16) encourages use of both `start` and `main` for asynchronous operations. In their discussion about `main` in conjunction with asynchronous operations they say, "Although you could perform the task in the `start` method, implementing the task using [`main`] can result in a cleaner separation of your setup and task code."

Comment: You are correct, thanks I was doing it in `start` for `asynchronous` operations but this is cleaner.

Comment: @Rob Thanks for sharing the  *revised version* of the asynchronous operation. But as the programming guide states also that `main` is *optional* for concurrent operations in practice it makes no difference to put the task code into `main` or (custom) `execute`. The general workflow is the same.

Comment: @vadian - Agreed. As I said in my answer, I renamed `execute` to `main` merely because it was a matter of convention; I didn't do it because I thought one _had_ to. It just struck me as really strange to introduce a completely different method name when it's so common (and explicitly contemplated by Apple) to use `main` for this purpose. My comment above was just in reaction to user1046037's assumption that `main` was _only_ for synchronous operations. I wonder if a similar misconception drove calebd's decision to use `execute` in the first place...

Comment: @Rob I'm using that class in a few projects and personally I like the concept of `execute` and `finish` as a differentiation to (implicitly called) synchronous `main` and to reflect `isExecuting / isFinishing` and the corresponding states.

Comment: @vadian - Fine. I think that's a little weird given that Apple explicitly discusses using `main` for this purpose in the [_Concurrency Programming Guide: Configuring Operations for Concurrent Execution_](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Conceptual/ConcurrencyProgrammingGuide/OperationObjects/OperationObjects.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008091-CH101-SW8) and in [the documentation for `main`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/operation/1407732-main), but to each his own. But it doesn't really matter.

Comment: @Rob Could you have a look at another Operation problem I am facing in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48137896/operation-went-isfinished-yes-without-being-started-by-the-queue-it-is-in

Comment: @Rob: What does "rw" stands for in the label name of the queue? Read/Write?

Comment: @VinGazoil - It stands for “reader-writer”, a synchronization pattern in which you use a concurrent queue, allowing concurrent reads, but using barrier for writes to ensure writes are properly synchronized.

Comment: @Rob - Thank you for this precision.

Comment: Amazing answer! Thank you.

Comment: @Rob Thanks for answering my other question. I'm still a bit confused about the `start()` method here. I subclassed the `AsynchronousOperation` class and created an [operation](https://pastebin.com/TaWyXSj3) for uploading files to S3. Do I manually have to call the `start()` method to begin the operation? Or does the `OperationQueue` take care of that?

Comment: @Isuru - Perhaps you can post to somewhere like gist.github.com, where I can post comments/corrections? In answer to your question, the operation queue will call `start` for you. But your `main` implementation isn’t quite right...

Comment: @Rob Do you think it's possible to perform the thread safety with the new concurrency API of Swift 5.5?

Comment: @vadian We'd just make it an `actor` and you're done. It's an extremely elegant solution and very simple. I'm already adopting actors and async-await in my apps and love the elegance of the code. (Earlier I was worried about how slow it was, but that looks like a broader performance difference between `concurrentPerform` and `async`-`await` task groups, not the `actor`.)

Comment: @Rob Thanks, with using `actor`s you mean to replace the entire `Operation` subclass with an `actor` and `OperationQueue` with a `TaskGroup` or an `AsyncSequence` pattern.

Comment: As it relates to this question, where doing `async`-`await` (which I’d prefer to operations in most use-cases), ensuring thread-safety with actors is definitely the way to go. In those rare cases where I might still use `Operation`, I still stick with traditional synchronization mechanisms. (I personally do not use reader-writer, though. Other approaches are more performant and just as elegant.)

Answer (score 8):

When using an updated code snippet from [Rob's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48104095/7564944), one should be aware of possibility of a bug, caused by this change:

> 7. Change finish so that it only moves to .finished state if isExecuting.

The above goes against Apple [docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsoperation?language=objc#1661262):

> In addition to simply exiting when an operation is cancelled, it is also important that you move a cancelled operation to the appropriate final state. Specifically, if you manage the values for the finished and executing properties yourself (perhaps because you are implementing a concurrent operation), you must update those properties accordingly. Specifically, you must change the value returned by finished to YES and the value returned by executing to NO. You must make these changes even if the operation was cancelled before it started executing.

This will cause a bug in a few cases. For example, if Operation Queue with "maxConcurrentOperationCount = 1" gets 3 async operations A B and C, then if all operations are cancelled during A, C will not get executed and the queue will be stuck on operation B.

Comment: so what's the solution here?

Comment: Good catch. I’ve fixed this in my answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

About your first question: stateQueue lock your operation when writing a new value to you operation state by:

```
    return stateQueue.sync(execute: {
            rawState
    })
```

And

```
    stateQueue.sync(flags: .barrier, execute: {
        rawState = newValue
    })
```

as your operation is asynchronous so before read or write one state another state can be called. Like you want to write isExecution but in the mean time isFinished already called. So to avoid this scenario stateQueue lock the operation state to be read and write until it finished its previous call. Its work like Atomic. Rather use dispatch queue you can use an extension to NSLock to simplify executing critical code from Advanced NSOperations sample code in WWDC 2015 https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2015/226/ from https://developer.apple.com/sample-code/wwdc/2015/downloads/Advanced-NSOperations.zip and you can implement like following:

```
private let stateLock = NSLock()

private dynamic var state: OperationState {
    get {
        return stateLock.withCriticalScope{ rawState } 
    }
    set {
        willChangeValue(forKey: "state")

        stateLock.withCriticalScope { 
            rawState = newValue
        }
        didChangeValue(forKey: "state")
    }
}
```

About your second question: Its a KVO notification for the read only property isReady, isExecuting, isFinished to manage the operation state. You can read this: http://nshipster.com/key-value-observing post till the end for better understanding about KVO.