# Operation went isFinished=YES without being started by the queue it is in

Tags: ios, swift, nsoperation

## Overview

- There is an asynchronous operation subclass
- Added this operation to the queue.
- I cancelled this operation before it starts.

## Runtime Error / Warning:

`SomeOperation went isFinished=YES without being started by the queue it is in`

## Question:

1. Is this something that can be ignored or it is something serious ?
2. How to resolve this ?
3. Is the workaround / solution provided at the end valid ?

## Code:

```
public class SomeOperation : AsyncOperation {

    //MARK: Start

    public override func start() {

        isExecuting = true

        guard !isCancelled else {
            markAsCompleted() //isExecuting = false, isFinished = true
            return
        }

        doSomethingAsynchronously { [weak self] in

            self?.markAsCompleted() //isExecuting = false, isFinished = true
        }
    }

    //MARK: Cancel

    public override func cancel() {

        super.cancel()
        markAsCompleted() //isExecuting = false, isFinished = true
    }
}
```

### Adding to Queue and cancelling:

```
//someOperation is a property in a class
if let someOperation = someOperation {
    queue.addOperation(someOperation)
}

//Based on some condition cancelling it
someOperation?.cancel()
```

## Is this valid a solution ?

```
public override func cancel() {

    isExecuting = true //Just in case the operation was cancelled before starting

    super.cancel()
    markAsCompleted()
}
```

## Note:

- `markAsCompleted` sets `isExecuting = false` and `isFinished = true`
- `isExecuting`, `isFinished` are properties which are synchronised `KVO`

Comment: Please show how you add the operation to the queue and how you cancel it.

Comment: Updated answer with a new section called `Adding to Queue and cancelling`

Comment: When you add an operation to a queue, it isn't started immediately. It is queued.. You need to check in your `cancel` operation if `isCancelled` or `isFinished`.. Then in your start operation, check the same..

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The key problem is that your `markAsCompleted` is triggering `isFinished` when the operation is not `isExecuting`. I'd suggest you just fix that `markAsCompleted` to only do this if `isExecuting` is true. This reduces the burden on subclasses doing any complicated state tests to figure out whether they need to transition to `isFinished` or not.

That having been said, I see three basic patterns when writing cancelable asynchronous operations:

1. If I'm dealing with some pattern where the canceling of the task will prevent it from transitioning executing operations to a `isFinished` state.

   In that case, I must have `cancel` implementation manually finish the executing operations. For example:

   ```
   class FiveSecondOperation: AsynchronousOperation {
       var block: DispatchWorkItem?

       override func main() {
           block = DispatchWorkItem { [weak self] in
               self?.finish()
               self?.block = nil
           }

           DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 5, execute: block!)
       }

       override func cancel() {
           super.cancel()

           if isExecuting {
               block?.cancel()
               finish()
           }
       }
   }
   ```

   Focusing on the `cancel` implementation, because if I cancel the `DispatchWorkItem` it won't finish the operation, I therefore need to make sure that `cancel` will explicitly finish the operation itself.
2. Sometimes, when you cancel some asynchronous task, it will call its completion handler automatically for you, in which case `cancel` doesn't need to do anything other than cancel the that task and call super. For example:

   ```
   class GetOperation: AsynchronousOperation {
       var url: URL
       weak var task: URLSessionTask?

       init(url: URL) {
           self.url = url
           super.init()
       }

       override func main() {
           let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { data, _, error in
               defer { self.finish() }  // make sure to finish the operation

               // process `data` & `error` here
           }
           task.resume()
           self.task = task
       }

       override func cancel() {
           super.cancel()
           task?.cancel()
       }
   }
   ```

   Again, focusing on `cancel`, in this case we don't touch the "finished" state, but just cancel `dataTask` (which will call its completion handler even if you cancel the request) and call the `super` implementation.
3. The third scenario is where you have some operation that is periodically checking `isCancelled` state. In that case, you don't have to implement `cancel` at all, as the default behavior is sufficient. For example:

   ```
   class DisplayLinkOperation: AsynchronousOperation {
       private weak var displayLink: CADisplayLink?
       private var startTime: CFTimeInterval!
       private let duration: CFTimeInterval = 2

       override func main() {
           startTime = CACurrentMediaTime()
           let displayLink = CADisplayLink(target: self, selector: #selector(handleDisplayLink(_:)))
           displayLink.add(to: .main, forMode: .commonModes)
           self.displayLink = displayLink
       }

       @objc func handleDisplayLink(_ displayLink: CADisplayLink) {
           let percentComplete = (CACurrentMediaTime() - startTime) / duration

           if percentComplete >= 1.0 || isCancelled {
               displayLink.invalidate()
               finish()
           }

           // now do some UI update based upon `elapsed`
       }
   }
   ```

   In this case, where I've wrapped a display link in an operation so I can manage dependencies and/or encapsulate the display link in a convenient object, I don't have to implement `cancel` at all, because the default implementation will update `isCancelled` for me, and I can just check for that.

Those are three basic `cancel` patterns I generally see. That having been said, updating `markAsCompleted` to only trigger `isFinished` if `isExecuting` is a good safety check to make sure you can never get the problem you described.

---

By the way, the `AsynchronousOperation` that I used for the above examples is as follows, adapted from [Trying to Understand Asynchronous Operation Subclass](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43561169). BTW, what you called `markAsCompleted` is called `finish`, and it sounds like you're triggering the `isFinished` and `isExecuting` KVO via a different mechanism, but the idea is basically the same. Just check the current state before you trigger `isFinished` KVO:

```
open class AsynchronousOperation: Operation {

    /// State for this operation.

    @objc private enum OperationState: Int {
        case ready
        case executing
        case finished
    }

    /// Concurrent queue for synchronizing access to `state`.

    private let stateQueue = DispatchQueue(label: Bundle.main.bundleIdentifier! + ".rw.state", attributes: .concurrent)

    /// Private backing stored property for `state`.

    private var rawState: OperationState = .ready

    /// The state of the operation

    @objc private dynamic var state: OperationState {
        get { return stateQueue.sync { rawState } }
        set { stateQueue.sync(flags: .barrier) { rawState = newValue } }
    }

    // MARK: - Various `Operation` properties

    open         override var isReady:        Bool { return state == .ready && super.isReady }
    public final override var isExecuting:    Bool { return state == .executing }
    public final override var isFinished:     Bool { return state == .finished }
    public final override var isAsynchronous: Bool { return true }

    // MARK: - KVN for dependent properties

    open override class func keyPathsForValuesAffectingValue(forKey key: String) -> Set<String> {
        if ["isReady", "isFinished", "isExecuting"].contains(key) {
            return [#keyPath(state)]
        }

        return super.keyPathsForValuesAffectingValue(forKey: key)
    }

    // MARK: - Foundation.Operation

    public final override func start() {
        if isCancelled {
            state = .finished
            return
        }

        state = .executing

        main()
    }

    /// Subclasses must implement this to perform their work and they must not call `super`. The default implementation of this function throws an exception.

    open override func main() {
        fatalError("Subclasses must implement `main`.")
    }

    /// Call this function to finish an operation that is currently executing

    public final func finish() {
        if isExecuting { state = .finished }
    }
}
```

Comment: Awesome explanation, thanks a ton !!! I was under the impression that you needed to set `isFinished = true` for the dependencies to trigger. Now from your explanation I learn that only executing operations need to be set to `isFininished = true`. Just calling the `super.cancel` is sufficient for operations that haven't started. I will override `markAsCompleted` to check for `isExecuting`

Comment: I also noticed that when an operation (in queue) that has hasn't started is cancelled, it starts. I suppose the check in `start` to check if `isCancelled` catches it and handles it. So for my example (like in your case 3) there is no need to override cancel. As you suggested would need to fix `markAsCompleted` to add the check for `isExecuting`.

Comment: Just curious in your `AsynchronousOperation.start` would it be better to set `state = executing` before checking is `isCancelled` so that when operation is cancelled (that hasn’t started) and operation invokes `start` and `executing` is set before it is set to `finished` ?

Comment: @user1046037 - If you go back to the original [Concurrency Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Conceptual/ConcurrencyProgrammingGuide/OperationObjects/OperationObjects.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008091-CH101-SW8), in their `start` implementation, they check if it was canceled. If canceled, they trigger the `isFinished` to `false` KVN and return immediately. They only do the `isExecuting` to `true` KVN if the operation wasn't canceled.

Comment: @user1046037 - "I also noticed that when an operation (in queue) that hasn't been started is canceled, it starts." ... That's not strictly true. For example, if I add two operations to serial queue and then `queue.cancelAllOperations()` when half way through the first operation, I'll see the second op start and then immediately cancel. But that isn't always the case. For example, in the same scenario, if I just cancel the second op, then I'll see it cancel without ever starting. It just depends upon how you cancel the operations.

Comment: Thanks a lot Rob, it has quite a few intricate details I didn't notice, think I need to test more

Comment: The operations `completionBlock` is not called if the OP was cancelled.

Comment: Those examples of using cancel are great! Do you think it would be better to call `super.cancel()` after cancelling your own work (i.e.call it at the end of the function)?  It's my understanding that `super` will call `start()` to immediately flush the operation from the queue.

Comment: @Rob In your `AsynchronousOperation` subclass, if the operation is cancelled before it starts, then it is later started, won't it fail to reach the `.finished` state? Because in `start()` you check if it is cancelled, and if so, call `finish()` and return. But in `finish()` you only move to the `.finished` state if the current state was `.executing`, which seemingly leaves no way to reach `.finished`. I'd assume this was just a sample-code oversight, but you've put such an emphasis on this `finish()` behavior (in this answer and the related one), that I feel I must have missed something?

Comment: Hi @Rob in this         if isCancelled { finish() ; return }  why there is need of calling finish() as it wont do anything because it is checking for state isExecuting and here it won't be true. correct me if there is any scenario where this could be useful.

Comment: @justinpawela - You are correct. It should just set `state` to `.finished` in `start`. I’ve corrected that above.

Comment: @Rob I have been using AsynOperation class for download some data from url which is asynchronous. I have read in the doc that asynchronous task is ignored if added to a queue, I am having hard time understanding this, Please help. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/operation . "When you add an operation to an operation queue, the queue ignores the value of the isAsynchronous property and always calls the start() method from a separate thread. Therefore, if you always run operations by adding them to an operation queue, there is no reason to make them asynchronous."

Comment: Apple has really made a mess of this. In short, they’re right, that they don’t care about `isAsynchronous` in conjunction w queues. At the same time, `isAsynchronous` says: “The value of this property is `true` for operations that run asynchronously with respect to the current thread or `false` for operations that run synchronously on the current thread.” So, while ignored when using operation queues, but I think it’s valuable for property to reflect the operation’s actual underlying behavior. Plus, it will also work if you ever use it in situation where you `start` it manually yourself.