# NSDocument: AsyncOperation I never called

Tags: swift, nsdocument

Some of the time when using my Document-based mac app (Xcode 10, Swift 4.2, macOS 10.13.5), I get the following error in the console:

> _NSDocumentBasicAsyncOperation 0x60c000233c40 went isFinished=YES without being started by the queue it is in

I understand how this can happen when you're using asynchronous operations (see, e.g., [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48137896/operation-went-isfinished-yes-without-being-started-by-the-queue-it-is-in)), but I don't. This is something Cocoa does all by itself, so my question is how worried should I be, and how can I find out where this error comes from? I am overriding a number of functions in NSDocumentController and NSDocument; I suspect that it's something in NSDocument (I get one of these per open document), but I'm stumped where to start troubleshooting, and curious as to what may be going on.

Comment: Were you ever able to sort this out? I'm running into the same problem. Also in a NSDocument based Mac app.

Comment: Nope, still happening. I can confirm, however, that this happens with the template straight out of the box: create a new app, use documents, build and run, quit the app from the menu, and the error will occur.

Comment: Just ran into this on macOS Catalina.

Comment: Have this in macOS Catalina in Obj-C too.

Comment: March 2022: Have this problem too (on Catalina), suddenly appeared in an app which did not exhibit this problem before. But it does not appear to have any side effects.