# Weak DispatchGroup in closures and other GCD questions

Tags: ios, swift, asynchronous, grand-central-dispatch

Swift closures strongly capture reference types.

DispatchGroup is a reference type.

My questions have to do with the following code:

```
func getUsername(onDone: @escaping (_ possUsername: String?) -> ())
{
    //Post request for username that calls onDone(retrievedUsername)...
}

func getBirthdate(using username: String?, onDone: @escaping (_ possBday: String?) -> ())
{
    //Post request for token that calls onDone(retrievedToken)...
}

func asyncTasksInOrder(onDone: @escaping (_ resultBDay: String?) -> ())
{
    let thread = DispatchQueue(label: "my thread", qos: .userInteractive, attributes: [],
                               autoreleaseFrequency: .workItem, target: nil)
    thread.async { [weak self, onDone] in
        guard let self = self else {
            onDone(nil)
            return
        }
        let dg = DispatchGroup()        //This is a reference type
        var retrievedUsername: String?
        var retrievedBday: String?

        //Get username async first
        dg.enter()
        self.getUsername(onDone: {[weak dg](possUsername) in
            retrievedUsername = possUsername
            dg?.leave() //DG is weak here
        })
        dg.wait()

        //Now that we've waited for the username, get bday async now
        dg.enter()
        self.getBirthdate(using: retrievedUsername, onDone: {[weak dg](possBday) in
            retrievedBday = possBday
            dg?.leave() //DG is also weak here
        })
        dg.wait()

        //We've waited for everything, so now call the return callback
        onDone(retrievedBday)
    }
}
```

So the two closures inside of `asyncTasksInOrder(onDone:)` each capture `dg`, my DispatchGroup.

1. Is it even necessary to capture my dispatch group?
2. If I don't capture it, how would I even know I've got a retain cycle?
3. What if the dispatch group evaporates during one of the callback executions? Would it even evaporate since it's waiting?
4. Is it unnecessarily expensive to instantiate a Dispatch**Queue** like this often (disregarding the `.userInteractive`)? I'm asking this particular question because spinning up threads in Android is extremely expensive (so expensive that JetBrains has dedicated lots of resources towards Kotlin coroutines).
5. How does `dg.notify(...)` play into all of this? Why even have a notify method when `dg.wait()` does the same thing?

I feel like my understanding of GCD is not bulletproof, so I'm asking to build some confidence. Please critique as well if there's anything to critique. The help is truly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) No, the dispatch group is captured implicitly. You don't even need to capture `self` in `async` because GCD closures don't cause retain cycles.

2) There is no retain cycle.

3) Actually you are misusing `DispatchGroup` to force an asynchronous task to become synchronous.

4) No, GCD is pretty lightweight.

5) The main purpose of `DispatchGroup` is to `notify` when all asynchronous tasks – for example in a repeat loop – are completed regardless of the order.

---

A better solution is to nest the asynchronous tasks. With only two tasks the *pyramid of doom* is manageable.

```
func asyncTasksInOrder(onDone: @escaping (String?) -> Void)
{
    let thread = DispatchQueue(label: "my thread", qos: .userInteractive, autoreleaseFrequency: .workItem)
    thread.async {       

        //Get username async first
        self.getUsername { [weak self] possUsername in
            guard let self = self else { onDone(nil); return }

            //Now get bday async
            self.getBirthdate(using: possUsername) { possBday in

               //Now call the return callback
                onDone(possBday)
            } 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Ah, but this is only a small example (I should have mentioned that I want this to scale). I always want to avoid the pyramid of doom. So if I'm misusing DispatchGroup, what's the best way to perform a lot of async tasks in order?

Comment: For example with a serial OperationQueue and an [asynchronous Operation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43561169/trying-to-understand-asynchronous-operation-subclass)