# How to pause operation queue in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, nsoperationqueue

I have a couple of operations to perform on the IoT device from iOS App. So All my operations are in OperationsQueue with serial operations.

Here I want to perform one operation at a time and each operation needs to wait until I get a response from the IoT device.

Here IoT device response will take time to send back. so how to wait for the current operation in operation queue until I get a response from IoT.

So is there any way to pause current running operation until getting a response from IoT and then I will resume it so that the next operation in operation queue will start.

I tried with Sleep operation But it required time, but we can not guarantee about IoT device response.

Any suggestions would appreciate it. Thank you in advance.

Comment: maybe waitUntilAllOperationsAreFinished() on OperationsQueue can help you to do that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The basic idea is that you don’t pause (or wait, or sleep), but rather you define a “concurrent” operation (see discussion of concurrent operations [in the documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/operation#overview)) that doesn’t trigger the [`isFinished`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/operation/1413540-isfinished) KVO until the device responds.

A simple way to do this is to write a concurrent operation class, like the [one shown in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48104095/1271826). Then your IoT operation can subclass that `AsynchronousOperation` class, and just call `finish()` when the device responds.

Then your operation queue (which presumably has a `maxConcurrentOperationCount` of `1`, or perhaps is using dependencies), will not start an operation until the prior operation has finished.

Comment: Rob, Thank you for the response I will work on it and let you know.

Comment: Rob, Many Thanks and i worked with sample and it is working as i expected.

Answer (score 2):

As [Rob](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1271826/rob) said, you can implement Asynchronous Operation class and subclass from it your **IoT** operation. For me it looks like the most preferred way to implement yr case.

**As an alternative**, in cases where you need to continue the process only after some asynchronous event in another thread completed, you can use [**NSCondition**](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nscondition). This is a mechanism from obj-c that provide an easy way to wait for a condition to occur.

Here is example:

```swift
let cond = NSCondition()
var available = false
var sharedString = ""

class WriterThread: Thread {

    override func main() {
        for _ in 0..<5 {
            cond.lock()
            sharedString = ""
            available = true
            cond.signal() // Notify and wake up the waiting thread/s
            cond.unlock()
        }
    }
}

class PrinterThread: Thread {

    override func main(){
        for _ in 0..<5 { //Just do it 5 times
            cond.lock()
            while(!available) {   //Protect from spurious signals
                cond.wait()
            }
            print(SharedString)
            sharedString = ""
            available = false
            cond.unlock()
        }
    }
}

let writet = WriterThread()
let printt = PrinterThread()
printt.start()
writet.start()
```

Comment: Gringo, Thank you for your time to respond. i got a solution.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a `DispatchQueue` and call `.suspend()` when you send the operation, and have the code that gets the response call `.resume()`. Then wherever you want to wait for the response before continuing, just put a dummy `queue.sync({ print("done waiting")})` and it will automatically wait until `.resume()` has been called before printing and continuing.

```
import Dispatch
var queue = DispatchQueue(label: "queue")

func sendOperationToIoTDevice(){
    //send the operation
    //...
    queue.suspend()
}
```

...

```
//whatever code gets the response:
    //get response
    //...
    queue.resume()
```

...

```
//main code

sendOperationToIoTDevice()
queue.sync { print("done waiting") } // will hang here until .resume() is called
```