# OperationQueue wait for async task to be done

Tags: ios, swift, nsoperationqueue

I am trying to understand `OperationQueue`'s and its advantages over the `DispatchQueue`. So when I learn dependencies between Operations I think I can use over the DispatchGroups but I am still trying to understand how can I make them wait for each other without using `Semaphore` or `DispatchGroup`

I started with:

```
let customQueue = OperationQueue()

let fetchIDOperation = Operation()
let fetchUserPhotoOperation = Operation()

customQueue.maxConcurrentOperationCount = 1

fetchUserPhotoOperation.completionBlock = {
    print("photos are fetching")
}

fetchIDOperation.completionBlock = {
    let url = URL.init(string: "http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1")!
    
    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, _, err) in
        guard err == nil, let data = data else {
            print("err")
            return
        }
        
        let a = try! JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: .allowFragments) as! [String: Any]
        print("json > ", a)
        
    }.resume()
    
}

fetchUserPhotoOperation.addDependency(fetchIDOperation)

customQueue.addOperation(fetchIDOperation)
customQueue.addOperation(fetchUserPhotoOperation)

fetchIDOperation.start()
```

The output is

```
ids are fetching
photos are fetching
json >  ["completed": 0, "userId": 1, "id": 1, "title": delectus aut autem]
```

I want that `OperationQueue` for photos one should start after the async task done in `fetchIDOperation`.

When I search for similar problems in Stackoverflow, in some answers there's referred to be using `DispatchSemaphore`. I really loved using the `dependency` functionality of the API, so is there an easy way to achieve this way without using semaphore or dispatchgroup?

Thanks in advance

Comment: A real great explaination with a sample on working async queue (I used a inspired by it for that): https://www.avanderlee.com/swift/asynchronous-operations/ https://github.com/AvdLee/AsyncOperations

Comment: `Operation` is synchronous by default. If it contains an asynchronous task `isFinished` is called before the asynchronous task completes. Look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43561169/trying-to-understand-asynchronous-operation-subclass/43761518?). The answer of Rob describes an asynchronous version of `Operation`

Comment: huge thanks @vadian and @Larme, I started with analyzing mock `AsyncOperation` class of avanderlee, then I worked it out for my example. But I would love to ask if this is the right place. ```willChangeValue(forKey: "isFinished")
            lockQueue.sync(flags: [.barrier]) {
                _isFinished = newValue
            }
            didChangeValue(forKey: "isFinished")```  
normally isFinished property is getOnly, is this hack safe? And why we have to use `willChangeValue(for:)` and `didChangeValue(for:)` functions?

Comment: You don't need `willChangeValue` and `didChangeValue`. In Swift `dynamic` enables KVO. See the answer in the link in my first comment. I'm using this class myself in a few projects.

Comment: ```swift
@objc private dynamic var state: OperationState {
        get { return stateQueue.sync { _state } }
        set { stateQueue.async(flags: .barrier) { self._state = newValue } }
}```
yeah, I learned the true way of usage of `dynamic` thank you!

Comment: I probably have a different opinion on OperationQueues. I would avoid it whenever possible and use plain GCD. The dependency feature is nice, however OperationQueues don't provide a mechanism to process the output from one operation within another (chaining output -> input). Even creating custom Operations _correctly_ is far more complicated than it ought to be. So, IMHO, you should only use OperationQueues once you are very familiar with GCD and know a lot of thread-safe programming. Alternatively, switch to Combine.