# Modifying actor property from two different tasks

Tags: swift, task, actor, swift-concurrency

`Converter` is an object that does some work in background. On the UI there is a button that allows users to stop `Converter` operations. This object works using up to 5 threads. To increase/decrease number of threads I'm using an `Actor`, that is also used to flag the `isRunning` property. The skeleton is something like this.

```swift
fileprivate let MAX_THREADS = 5
 
actor ConverterData {
    var threads: Int = 0
    var isRunning: Bool = false 

    func incThreads() {
        threads += 1
    }

    fun decThreads() {
        threads -= 1
    }

    func setIsRunning(_ flag: Bool) {
        isRunning = flag
    }
}

class Converter {
    private var converterData = ConverterData()

    func start() {
        Task {
            await converterData.setIsRunning(true)
            while await converterData.isRunning { // here always true
                if await converterData.threads < MAX_THREADS {
                    await converterData.incThreads() // threads increase and the new number is seen by this if
                    // Create a new task
                    ...
                }
                try? await Task.sleep(nanoseconds: 1000000000)
            }
        }
    }

    func stop() {
        Task {
            await converterData.setIsRunning(false)
            // This change is seen here, in this task, but not in the previous task, inside the while.
            print(await converterData.isRunning) // correct: false
        }
    }
}
```

As shown in code, using comments, the problem seems to be as follows: when I change actor properties from a `Task`, other tasks do not see that changes, but still see only their own changes.

Maybe I'm missing the real concept behind actors?

**Long story**
Using the `NSSpeechSynthetizerDelegate` I add an `.aiff` URL to the actor `var aiff: [URL]` property each time the TTS finishes writing the spoken file. The `while` inside the `start()` method is used to check whether the main loop should continue. Inside this loop it checks if `aiff` array contains URLs to convert to MP3. This is also the reason I'm using the `sleep(nanoseconds:)` method inside the `start()`.

When converter detects that all `.aiff` files are converted to MP3 it should terminate the `while` inside the `start()` and terminate the Task. Also the task should be stopped even if a button on the UI is pressed. I'm trying to simplify.

```
actor ConverterData {
    var threads: Int = 0
    var aiff: [URL] = []
    var isRunning: Bool = false 
    var totalMp3Converted: Int = 0

    // Methods to inc/dec threads
    ...


    // Method to set isRunning, appending
    // URLs to aiff and to inc totalMp3Converted.
    ...
}

class Converter {
    private var converterData = ConvertedData()

    func start() // maybe async {
        Task { // if not async
            // while to check if is running, if so
            // and if current number of aiff-to-mp3 threads is
            // less than MAX_THREADS starts a new 
            // conversion thread (if aiff array contains 
            // at least one aiff URL).

            // Maybe it can be removed? I wouldn't stress 
            // the while too much with continuous checking :-)
            try? await Task.sleep(nanoseconds: 1_000_000_000) 
        }

    func stop() // maybe async {
        Task { // if not async
            await converterData.setIsRunning(false)
            // This should terminate the while in the
            // start() method. 
        }
    }
}
```

And something like this:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    private let converter = Converter() 

    var body: some View {
        // This if using the @Rob hint about using 
        // async Converter methods
        Button("Start") {
            Task {
                await converter.start()
            }
        }

        Button("Stop") {
            Task {
                await converter.stop() 
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Hope this is clear enough!

Comment: Unrelated, but you should be wary of unstructured concurrency, where `start` and `stop` launch new top level tasks on the current actor (which is what `Task {…}` does). They should just be `async` functions, and the caller can can wrap that in a `Task` if it needs/wants (which it can cancel if it wants). But you want to avoid launching orphaned unstructured concurrency.

Comment: @Rob thanks for your reply. I edited my question to add more context, hoping it will be clearer. Meanwhile I'm studying your hint about using an async converter inside an external Task.

Comment: The `while` loop is not the right solution, IMHO. I'd suggest you stop trying to tell what what you were trying to do (with the `while` and `sleep`), and instead focus on what you need it to do. If you just want it to process them as they come in, use `AsyncChannel`. If you want to constrain the degree of concurrency, use task group with `next`. If you want to process them sequentially, that's even easier.

Comment: @Rob thanks again. I'm really new to these "new" APIs. In earlier versions of my app I used to use dispatch_queue. I will trying to study AsyncChanel. It seems to me the right solution (dropping the min threads requirement). May I ask you a basic example to start with?

Comment: See latter part of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73072799/1271826) where I’ve got a download manager that will perform a max of four requests at a time, but for which I send requests to the channel, as needed. That is effectively the solution I included in the second half of my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76283315/1271826), below.

Comment: @Rob really thank you. I missed the second part of your answer yesterday night. Maybe I was a little tired. OK I will give it a try. It seems to me the right method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code works fine. The property does get updated. See https://gist.github.com/robertmryan/82107541c5ec227ef272da2edc0531f0.

Now, if the omitted code, “create a new task”, is (a) isolated to the current actor; and (b) doing something slow and synchronous, then that could result in the behavior you described. But it works for me.

---

That having been said, spinning (even with the pause in the loop) is an anti-pattern. If you find yourself writing code that spins, that is a red flag, an indication that you can optimized this.

If you want to run no more than `MAX_THREADS` tasks concurrently, I would use a task group, inserting a `group.next()` call after you reach a certain level. E.g.,

```swift
class Converter {
    func process(_ items: [Item]) async {
        await withTaskGroup(of: Void.self) { group in
            for (index, item) in items.enumerated() {
                if index >= MAX_THREADS {
                    await group.next()
                }
                
                group.addTaskUnlessCancelled { await self.convert(item) }
            }
        }
    }
    
    nonisolated func convert(_ item: Item) async { … }
}
```

And, if the concern is that you don’t have the full array of items when you start this process, then use an [`AsyncChannel`](https://github.com/apple/swift-async-algorithms/blob/main/Sources/AsyncAlgorithms/AsyncAlgorithms.docc/Guides/Channel.md), of the [Swift Async Algorithms](https://github.com/apple/swift-async-algorithms/tree/main), and then you can do a `for`-`await`-`in`. E.g.,

```swift
actor Converter {
    private let channel = AsyncChannel<Item>()

    /// Monitor channel for new items
    ///
    /// Run no more than `MAX_THREADS` at a time.

    func monitorChannel() async {
        await withTaskGroup(of: Void.self) { group in
            var index = 0
            for await item in channel {
                index += 1
                if index > MAX_THREADS {
                    await group.next()
                }

                group.addTaskUnlessCancelled { await self.convert(item) }
            }
        }
    }

    /// Append additional item to channel

    func append(_ item: Item) async {
        await channel.send(item)
    }
}
```

But if you find yourself spinning or keeping track of a count of active processes, then you may want to refactor/simplify that, as shown above.

Comment: The `AsyncChannel` was the right solution!