Swift's concurrent tasks with Mutex similar to Kotlin's Coroutines
So I have the following Kotlin's sample code to work with async stuff by using Coroutines and I want to achieve the same with Swift:
Kotlin:
private val mutex = Mutex()

private suspend fun startConcurrentJobs() = coroutineScope {
    launch {
        asyncJob()
    }
    launch {
        asyncJob()
    }
}

private suspend fun asyncJob() {
    subAsyncJob1() // this job can be called by different coroutines at the same time

    mutex.withLock {
        // this job is not allowed to be called by different coroutines at the same time
        subAsyncJob2()
    }
}

private suspend fun subAsyncJob1() {
    // TODO: Concurrent work
}

private suspend fun subAsyncJob2() {
    // TODO: Protected work (exclusive access)
}

I have come up with the following two implementations in Swift:

by using Actor:

actor Mutex {
    func lockAsyncJob<T>(_ operation: () async -> T) async -> T {
        return await operation()
    }
}

let mutex = Mutex()

private func startConcurrentJobs() async {
    await withTaskGroup(of: Void.self) { taskGroup in
        taskGroup.addTask {
            await self.asyncJob()
        }
        taskGroup.addTask {
            await self.asyncJob()
        }
    }
}

private func asyncJob() async {
    await subAsyncJob1() // this job can be called by different tasks at the same time
    
    await mutex.lockAsyncJob {
        // this job is not allowed to be called by different tasks at the same time
        await subAsyncJob2()
    }
}

private func subAsyncJob1() async {
    // TODO: Concurrent work
}

private func subAsyncJob2() async {
    // TODO: Protected work (exclusive access)
}


by using DispatchQueue:

let mutexQueue = DispatchQueue(label: "com.example.mutexQueue")

private func startConcurrentJobs() async {
    await withTaskGroup(of: Void.self) { taskGroup in
        taskGroup.addTask {
            await self.asyncJob()
        }
        taskGroup.addTask {
            await self.asyncJob()
        }
    }
}

private func asyncJob() async {
    await subAsyncJob1() // this job can be called by different tasks at the same time
    
    await withCheckedContinuation { continuation in
        mutexQueue.async {
            // This block is executed serially on the queue, ensuring exclusive access
            Task {
                await self.subAsyncJob2()
                continuation.resume()
            }
        }
    }
}

private func subAsyncJob1() async {
    // TODO: Concurrent work
}
    
private func subAsyncJob2() async {
    // TODO: Protected work (exclusive access)
}

So I guess both implementations should achieve the same results as with Kotlin's Coroutines, though it's a bit tricky to handle sync code in Swift comparing to Kotlin's Mutex.
There are also NSLock, DispatchSemaphore in Swift but it's not safe and cause deadlocks, it's design for threads.
I didn't work much with Swift, so I'm trying to find the correct approach.

Neither of your solutions are correct. Actors are re-entrant, but Kotlin mutexes are not. And you are only sending the creation of a Task to a dispatch queue, not the operation that Task will run. The dispatch queue will be ready to run the next operation before the code in the Task finishes.

I would suggest looking into NSOperation. Generally we don't do locks in cocoa programming anymore. We use dispatch queues or Combine framework to ensure proper data protection. There are many different approaches, but Apple has gone through great lengths to shield us from those things. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsoperation

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/combine You may also look at Grand Central Dispatch directly. There is also I believe a Stanford class on protecting data structures in swift on YouTube CS193p I unfortunately don't know which session.

@Sweeper yeah, I just want to find quick example to achieve similar result, no really much time to go deep in learning Swift and its concurrency stuff at this moment

In Swift you don't need a Mutex here. You just need an actor and a Task.
actor A {
    // The actor removes the need for a Mutex here
    private var job2Task: Task<Void, Never>?

    // I'm not sure why this is private in your example. How do you run this?
    public func startConcurrentJobs() async {
        await withTaskGroup(of: Void.self) { taskGroup in
            taskGroup.addTask {
                await self.asyncJob()
            }
            taskGroup.addTask {
                await self.asyncJob()
            }
        }
    }

    // Here's all the magic (well, nothing magic, just actors)
    private func asyncJob() async {

        // this job can be called by different tasks at the same time
        await subAsyncJob1()

        // Wait for the current task (if any) to complete. This is extremely
        // flexible. You could check for `!= nil` and return here or throw an
        // error or cancel the previous task. But it's ok for other callers to
        // re-enter `asyncJob()` while we `await`. The loop is because another
        // waiter might get in front of us in line.
        // Note that this is an "unfair" lock. There's no promise that a waiter
        // will ever be served if this is highly contended. (See below.)
        while job2Task != nil {
            await job2Task?.value
        }

        // Just to prove the point. You don't need this.
        assert(job2Task == nil)

        if Task.isCancelled { return }

        // This is an actor. We can know that nothing has occurred between the
        // `await task.value` and now. And because the end of this Task will set
        // `task = nil`, we know that it is now nil.
        job2Task = Task {
            // When the task completes, no matter how, clear it
            defer { job2Task = nil }
            await subAsyncJob2()
        }

        // Again, no race conditions. This is an actor. We know nothing can
        // happen between assigning `task` and awaiting it here. You could even
        // skip the `await` if you don't need it to finish before returning.
        await job2Task?.value
    }

    private func subAsyncJob1() async {
        // TODO: Concurrent work
    }

    private func subAsyncJob2() async {
        // TODO: Protected work (exclusive access)
    }
}

You can take this one step further and run job1 and job2 in parallel if they don't depend on each other:
private func asyncJob() async {

    await withTaskGroup(of: Void.self) { group in

        // Kick off Job1
        group.addTask { await self.subAsyncJob1() }

        // Wait for any previous Job2 to finish
        while job2Task != nil {
            await job2Task?.value
        }

        if Task.isCancelled { return }

        // Kick off Job2
        job2Task = Task {
            // When the task completes, no matter how, clear it
            defer { job2Task = nil }
            await subAsyncJob2()
        }

        // And wait for it in parallel with Job1
        group.addTask { await self.job2Task?.value }

        await group.waitForAll()
    }
}

In most cases you'll want to put the synchronization logic directly in asyncJob2 rather than in the caller like this, but it's very similar either way.

As mentioned in the comments above, note that this while loop is an unfair lock. Jobs do not run in any particular order. You can make a fair lock that orders the requests, but it can make things like cancellation and error handling a little harder to reason about. It looks like this:
// Make the property non-optional
private var job2Task: Task<Void, Never> = Task {}

private func asyncJob() async {
    await withTaskGroup(of: Void.self) { group in
        group.addTask { await self.subAsyncJob1() }

        // Each task awaits the former one. The `[...]` makes a local copy
        job2Task = Task { [job2Task] in
            await job2Task.value

            if Task.isCancelled { return }

            // When the task completes, no matter how, clear it
            await subAsyncJob2()
        }

        group.addTask { await self.job2Task.value }

        await group.waitForAll()
    }
}


Thanks! It's interesting how we can easily replace actor A to class A and everything stops working correct at runtime:), so await Task.value only works correct if it's used inside instance of actor, I don't really know anything about Actors yet but it looks quite difficult for newbies in Swift as for me. // I'm not sure why this is private in your example. How do you run this? I copied only functions from my sample ViewModel class (class MainViewModel: ObservableObject, ...), it's started from other place in the same class

Well I found an issue with your code, as soon as I add third task to the group taskGroup.addTask { await self.asyncJob() } inside startConcurrentJobs function, it still allows subAsyncJob2() function to be called by two tasks at the same time when the first task finishes with it, though it works correct with two tasks only for taskGroup inside startConcurrentJobs

It has nothing to do with the await. Everything stops working if this is a class because you get no protections on the properties, so it's not thread-safe. You can build this with a class but then you need to add a lock on Task. I've updated to fix the mistake I made for about more than 2 callers.

My answer has gotten to sprawl a bit, and I'd like to mark this as duplicate to a better version that already exists. @Rob (a different Rob) always explains this better than I do, and better handles the discussion of cancellation: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73072799/97337  Let me know if that other answer addresses your questions, and if not, I can adapt this to be better in light of that one.

yeah, it now works, but I have also tried that answer and it works as well for me, and that answer doesn't use while, so I guess I will choose it. Thanks again!
