# Swift 5.5 concurrency: Are scheduled Tasks serial to one another

Tags: swift, swift5, swift-concurrency

i saw this thread [Swift 5.5 Concurrency: how to serialize async Tasks to replace an OperationQueue with maxConcurrentOperationCount = 1?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70540541/swift-5-5-concurrency-how-to-serialize-async-tasks-to-replace-an-operationqueue)
but i am not clear on whether two scheduled Tasks will execute serially.  What i mean is, if i had a piece of code

```
func fetchImages() {
   Task.init {
     let fetch = await loadImages()
   }

   Task.init {
     let fetch1 = await loadImages1()
   }
}
```

will first task always finish before second task starts? The application i am trying to get is to execute task 1 as soon as possible (save time) but task 2 relies on the result of task 1 so it needs to wait for task 1 to finish before proceeding. Task 2 also is only conditionally triggered upon an event so they cannot be in the same Task.

Comment: Check this article: https://www.swiftbysundell.com/articles/task-based-concurrency-in-swift/ (the Sequencing portion of it). You will still have to adopt that solution to accommodate your "Task 2 also is only conditionally triggered upon an event" condition. I.e. maybe you will have task in a sequence, but cancel it if not needed, or maybe you will need a dynamic sequence.

Answer (score 5):

You asked:

> will first task always finish before second task starts?

No, it will not. Whenever you see `await`, that is a “suspension point” at which Swift concurrency is free to switch to another task. In short, these can run concurrently. Let me illustrate that with Xcode Instruments:

```swift
import os.log

private let log = OSLog(subsystem: "Test", category: .pointsOfInterest)

class Foo {
    func fetchImages() {
        Task {
            let fetch = await loadImages()
            print("done loadImages")
        }
        
        Task {
            let fetch1 = await loadImages1()
            print("done loadImages1")
        }
    }
    
    func loadImages() async {
        // start “points of interest” interval

        let id = OSSignpostID(log: log)
        os_signpost(.begin, log: log, name: #function, signpostID: id, "start")

        // perform 3-second asynchronous task

        try? await Task.sleep(nanoseconds: 3 * NSEC_PER_SEC)

        // end “points of interest” interval

        os_signpost(.end, log: log, name: #function, signpostID: id, "end")
    }

    func loadImages1() async {
        // start “points of interest” interval

        let id = OSSignpostID(log: log)
        os_signpost(.begin, log: log, name: #function, signpostID: id, "start")

        // perform 1-second asynchronous task

        try? await Task.sleep(nanoseconds: 1 * NSEC_PER_SEC)

        // end “points of interest” interval

        os_signpost(.end, log: log, name: #function, signpostID: id, "end")
    }
}
```

Profiling (in Xcode, either press <kbd>command</kbd>-<kbd>i</kbd> or choose from the menu, “Product” » “Profile”) this with the “time profiler” in Instruments, you can see that these run concurrently:

[image]

---

The trick is to have the second task `await` the first one. E.g.,

```swift
func fetchImages() {
    let firstTask = Task {
        let fetch = await loadImages()
        print("done loadImages")
    }
    
    Task {
        _ = await firstTask.result
        let fetch1 = await loadImages1()
        print("done loadImages1")
    }
}
```

Or you can store the first task in some property:

```swift
var firstTask: Task<Void, Never>?   // you may need to adjust the `Success` and `Failure` types to match your real example

func fetchImages() {
    firstTask = Task {
        let fetch = await loadImages()
        print("done loadImages")
    }
    
    Task {
        _ = await firstTask?.result
        let fetch1 = await loadImages1()
        print("done loadImages1")
    }
}
```

When you do that, you can see the sequential execution:

[image]

FWIW, this concept, of using `await` on the prior task was the motivating idea behind that [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70540541/swift-5-5-concurrency-how-to-serialize-async-tasks-to-replace-an-operationqueue) that you referenced. That is a more generalized rendition of the above. Hopefully this illustrates the mechanism outlined in that other answer.