# Serialising the calling of Task blocks from a non async environment

Tags: ios, swift

I am calling a function multiple times one after another and am trying to synchronise it so it happens serially. The issue is, the function contains a `Task`, which executes in parallel. I have serialized the internals of my `Task` using help from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70586879/362840) post. Here's an example of my code:

```
class MyClass {
    let taskSerializer = SerialTasks<Void>()

    func viewDidLoad() {
        someFunction(1)
        someFunction(2)
        someFunction(3)
    }

    func someFunction(_ value: Int) {
        Task {
            try await taskSerializer.add {
                try? await self.myAsyncFunction(value: value)
            }
        }
    }

    private func myAsyncFunction(value: Int) async throws {
        print(value)
    }
}

actor SerialTasks<Success> {
    private var previousTask: Task<Success, Error>?

    func add(block: @Sendable @escaping () async throws -> Success) async throws -> Success {
        let task = Task { [previousTask] in
            let _ = await previousTask?.result
            return try await block()
        }
        previousTask = task
        return try await task.value
    }
}
```

I expect to see 1, 2, 3 printed in order to the console. However, this is not always the case as sometimes 3 arrives to the `taskSerializer` before 2. How can I fix this?

UPDATE:

Replacing the code inside `someFunction` with this fixes the issue:

```
queue.async { [weak self] in
    guard let self = self else {
        return
    }
    self.semaphore.wait()
    Task {
        try? await self.myAsyncFunction(value: value)
        self.semaphore.signal()
    }
}
```

UPDATE 2:

I've tried an `AsyncStream`. However, this still prints elements in the wrong order sometimes, e.g. 1, 3, 2

```
class MyClass {
    lazy var stream: AsyncStream<Task<Void, Never>> = {
        AsyncStream { continuation in
            self.continuation = continuation
        }
    }()
    var continuation: AsyncStream<Task<Void, Never>>.Continuation?

    func viewDidLoad() {
        Task {
            for await tasks in stream {
                await tasks.value
            }
        }

        someFunction(1)
        someFunction(2)
        someFunction(3)
    }

    func someFunction(_ value: Int) {
        continuation?.yield(
            Task {
                try? await self.myAsyncFunction(value: value)
            }
        )
    }

    private func myAsyncFunction(value: Int) async throws {
        print(value)
    }
}
```

But apparently this is a bad idea to mix semaphores with Tasks.

Comment: You could use an AsyncSequence

Comment: Can you give an example? I've never used one before

Comment: I'd suggest watching the WWDC videos that are associated with the concept, as there's quite a bit to understand. But, they're well-suited to serialized steps, whereas using `Task`, as you've found out, is not

Comment: I think a semaphore would be easier ngl. Gonna try it out

Comment: Definitely do not use semaphores to manage dependencies in Swift concurrency. Apple is has been very explicit that semaphores are unsafe to manage dependencies between tasks.

Comment: The problem here is not that `SerialTask` runs them in parallel (because it doesn’t), but rather that there is a race between tasks created by repeated calls to `someFunction`. Do not conflate the order that the tasks start (which is not guaranteed) with the parallel execution (or non-parallel execution, as in this case).

Comment: @Rob If I wrap the `someFunction` Task in a `DispatchQueue` and then put `self.semaphore.wait()` before the Task call and `self.semaphore.signal()` after `myAsyncFunction` has finished, it solves the issue. What's wrong with that?

Comment: There is a race between tasks created but this is making sure that only one task is created at a time. I can also remove the `SerialTasks` code in that instance. Failing to see the issue, although it is awkward. But I haven't found any better way

Comment: Apple specifically gives guidance about not mixing concurrency paradigms. It'd be highly suggested to follow their advice to avoid unexpected situations

Comment: Hmm. I updated my code above to show what I meant by the way. Would you be able to give a simplistic version of how to stop races of Tasks using an AsyncSequence?

Comment: @Rob It would make sense to await them from one Task, but the issue is it has to come from a non concurrent source where they can't be wrapped in the same Task block. So the case i show has to be able to be handled. E.g. pressing a button rapidly

Comment: @Rob I've tried an AsyncStream but still experiencing the same race... Any ideas why? Updated my code again in my question

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/255452/discussion-between-rob-and-tometoyou).

Comment: Get rid of the floating Task and don’t mix GCD with the new concurrency. They are not compatible. Also look into actor

Comment: Is this relating to my solution that I posted? @loremipsum

Comment: Yes, you are using GCD to do what the new concurrency does by default. New new concurrency replaces the old stuff, they don’t mix.

Comment: Look into "global actor" I would post an answer but SO has stopped me from posting a 100% written by me answer because it says it is AI generated. LOL I guess SO's AI is trying to phase out its human trainers.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is not `SerialTasks`. The problem is that the caller, `someFunction`, itself, is launching a series of [unstructured concurrency](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/documentation/the-swift-programming-language/concurrency#Unstructured-Concurrency) tasks with `Task {…}` before it even gets to `SerialTasks`. Those tasks created by `someFunction` may not run in a strictly FIFO order and (unless you launched them from an actor-isolated context) they will run in parallel.

So, `SerialTasks` will run them sequentially in the order it receives them, but you are not adding them in order. Once you start adding tasks to `SerialTasks` in the wrong order, it is too late.

If you are launching a series of independent unstructured concurrency tasks to run in a FIFO manner, that is where you need to adopt the “await prior task” pattern illustrated by `SerialTasks`.

```swift
@MainActor
class MyClass2 {
    var previousTask: Task<Void, Error>?

    func startFifoSeries() {
        for i in 0 ..< 1_000 {
            someFunctionFifo(i)
        }
        print(#function, "done")
    }

    func someFunctionFifo(_ value: Int) {
        previousTask = Task { [previousTask] in
            _ = try await previousTask?.value
            try await self.myAsyncFunction(value: value)
        }
    }

    var previousValue: Int?

    private func myAsyncFunction(value: Int) async throws {
        if let previousValue, value < previousValue {
            print(value, "is less than previous value", previousValue)
        }
        previousValue = value
        …
    }
}
```

The bottom line is that the “await prior task” pattern is one way to ensure that they run in order and not in parallel. There are other patterns, too (e.g., an `AsyncSequence` such as [`AsyncChannel`](https://github.com/apple/swift-async-algorithms/blob/main/Sources/AsyncAlgorithms/AsyncAlgorithms.docc/Guides/Channel.md)). (As an aside, I isolated `MyClass2` to the main actor, but that is not necessary. You can obviously just make it an actor, itself, or isolate it to whatever actor you want. Just make sure it is actor-isolated if you are accessing properties.)

---

For the sake of future readers, I would be very wary of using unstructured concurrency without adding cancelation handling (or use a pattern that handles cancelation for you). See [Make tasks in Swift concurrency run serially](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73026499/make-tasks-in-swift-concurrency-run-serially/73072799#73072799).

Comment: The problem would still exist here though - startFifoSeries is still isolated to an actor. I have to launch tasks from outside of an actor/concurrent environment, like from the tap of a button. So I can’t tie the launching of them to an actor so this solution wouldn’t work

Comment: Hmm, okay I’ll try this later. If it works, I will mark it as the answer

Comment: To call `someFunctionFifo` from a non-concurrent/actor environment `previousTask` can't be isolated to an actor. Does that matter? Really appreciate the help here by the way.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/255491/discussion-between-rob-and-tometoyou).

Answer (score -2):

Okay I think I solved this using a custom `TaskQueue` class. This way all tasks are added into an array and executed sequentially, calling a completion block after the task completes which gets the next task from the queue.

```
class TaskQueue {
    private var taskQueue: [() async -> Void] = []
    private var queue = DispatchQueue(label: "myqueue")

    func addTask(task: @escaping () async -> Void) {
        queue.async { [weak self] in
          guard let self = self else {
            return
          }
          // Add the task to the queue
          self.taskQueue.append(task)
          // If there's only one task in the queue, start executing it
          if self.taskQueue.count == 1 {
            self.executeNextTask()
          }
        }
      }

      private func executeNextTask() {
        queue.async { [weak self] in
          guard let self = self else {
            return
          }
          // Check if there are tasks in the queue
          if taskQueue.isEmpty {
            return // No more tasks to execute
          }

          // Get the next task from the queue
          let nextTask = taskQueue.removeFirst()

          // Execute the task
          Task {
            await nextTask()
            // After the task completes, recursively execute the next task
            self.executeNextTask()
          }
        }
      }
  }

...

taskQueue.addTask {
   try? await self.myAsyncFunction(value: value)
}
```