# Get CLLocation data using an Operation

Tags: swift, cllocationmanager, operation

```
import Foundation
import CoreLocation

class LocationOperation: Operation, CLLocationManagerDelegate {

  // MARK: Properties
  private var manager: CLLocationManager?
  private let handler: (CLLocation) -> Void

  // MARK: Initialization
  init(locationHandler: @escaping (CLLocation) -> Void) {
    self.handler = locationHandler
    super.init()
  }

  // MARK: Main
  override func main() {
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
      let manager = CLLocationManager()
      manager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyNearestTenMeters
      manager.delegate = self
      manager.startUpdatingLocation()
    }
  }

  override func cancel() {
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
      self.stopLocationUpdates()
      super.cancel()
    }
  }

  private func stopLocationUpdates() {
    manager?.stopUpdatingLocation()
    manager = nil
  }

  // MARK: CLLocationManagerDelegate
  func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
    guard let location = locations.last,
      location.horizontalAccuracy <= manager.desiredAccuracy else {
        return
    }
    stopLocationUpdates()
    handler(location)
  }

  func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didFailWithError error: Error) {
    stopLocationUpdates()
    print("Failure to find location") // handle this eventually
    self.cancel()
  }
}
```

main finishes executing before CLLocationManager gets a chance to get the location and pass that to the passed in handler.  The first attempted solution was to override the isExecuting property and manually set it to true after I call handler(location) in (_:didUpdateLocations) but that's a read only property.  This [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24109701/nsoperation-property-overrides-isexecuting-isfinished/25961001) provided a way to do that, but I wasn't sure about the implementation.  **How do I stop the operation from finishing before it passes the location to the handler?** . Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two serious issues:

1. `manager` is declared locally in `main()` and get destroyed after `main()` exits.

   Replace

   ```
   private var manager: CLLocationManager?
   ```

   with

   ```
   private let manager = CLLocationManager()
   ```

   and delete the local variable

   <strike>`let manager = CLLocationManager()`</strike>

   in `main()`. I'd even prefer a `lazy` property.
2. You have to use an asynchronous `Operation` as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43561169/trying-to-understand-asynchronous-operation-subclass)

Comment: Good catch! I accidentally left the code where I declared manager in main().  The solution in the link works nicely.  Thanks.